# What is a cut pair in partially ordered class?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I haven't understood the definition of a ***cut*** in POSET.
Let $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$.
 Which of the following is a ***cut*** ?
a) $\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4, 5, 6, 7\}\}$ - Separates such that no element in Upper set(Second one) is less than Lower set(first one)
or
b) $\{\{1, 2, 4\}, \{3, 5, 6, 7\}\}$ - Just partition into two POSETS, without any restrictions.
or both?

Definition of a ***cut***:
If $A$ is a partially ordered class, then a cut of $A$ is pair $(L, U)$ of
nonempty subclasses of $A$ with the following properties:
i) $L ∩ U = Ø$ and $L ∪ U = A$.
ii) If $x ∈ L$ and $y \le x$, then $y ∈ L$. 
iii) If $x ∈ U$ and $y \ge x$, then $y ∈ U$.

[In this image ***a*** and ***f*** are not ordered. How can they be part of a ***cut*** ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrRS.png)

Comment: Definition of cut?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, I have added the definition of a cut in the question. please have a look at it.

Comment: It means that $A$ can be partitioned into two disjoint sets such that the elements of the first set are all lower bounds of the second set and the elements of the second set are upper bounds of the first set. With that in mind, this should be an easy problem.

Comment: @JohnDouma, I didn't get it. In the definition, I haven't seen any relation between L and U. Could you please elaborate it.

Comment: $L$ and $U$ are disjoint. Consider $u\in U$. If there exists $l\in L$, can $u$ be less than or equal to $l$?

Comment: @JohnDouma, The question may not be clear. To have clear understanding, I have added an image in the question.

Comment: The connected elements are ordered by height.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question about $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, I assume that the partial order is the usual $\leq$. Then it is easy to see that $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6,7\}\}$ is a cut, because it satisfies i), and all elements that are less than an element in $L = \{1,2,3\}$ is also in $L$, and all elements that are greater than an element in $U = \{4,5,6,7\}$ is also in $U$, so ii) and iii) are also satisfied.

However, $\{\{1,2,4\},\{3,5,6,7\}\}$ with $L = \{1,2,4\}$ and $U = \{3,5,6,7\}$ is not a cut because $4 \in L$ and $3 \leq 4$, but $4 \notin L$, so condition ii) is not satisfied. In fact, condition iii) is also not satisfied because $3 \in U$ and $4 \geq 3$, but $4 \notin U$.

For the question in your image, we can simply check the definition:

i) is clearly satisfied.

ii) $a \in L$ and the elements below $a$ are $b$ and $c$, and these are also in $L$. $b \in L$ and the only element below $b$ is $c$, which is also in $L$. $c \in L$, but there are no elements below $c$.

iii) $f \in U$ and the elements above $f$ are $d$ and $e$ which are also in $U$. $e \in U$ and the only element above $e$ is $d$, which is also in $U$. Finally, $d \in U$, but there are no elements above $d$.

Hence $L = \{a,b,c\}$ and $U = \{d,e,f\}$ determines a cut.

Comment: In the image **a** and **f** are not ordered. what if **a** is greater than **f** ? If you look the question, it is option b. So can we cut the set without knowing the order relation between elements like **a** and **f** ? please clarify it.

Comment: @krishna The elements are ordered by Fig. 1: $x \leq y$ if and only if there is a downward path from $y$ to $x$. It's true that $a$ and $f$ are "not ordered", they are incomparable in this order. So if you change the order to make them comparable, then the answer may of course be different.